# Rocket Chat - File uploading stacks at 0%

Tags: node.js, file-upload, rocket.chat

I'am trying to upload file into a channel. But nothing works. File uploadings stacks at 0% and not progress more.

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. Open any channel.
2. Upload any file or files.
3. Click submit button.

**Expected behavior:**

File completely uploaded and message successfully sent.

**Actual behavior:**
Stacks at 0% of file uploading.

**Server Setup Information:**

Version of Rocket.Chat Server: 1.3.2

Operating System: CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core)

Deployment Method:

https://rocket.chat/docs/installation/manual-installation/centos/

Number of Running Instances: 1

NodeJS Version: 8.11.4

MongoDB Version: 4.0.12

**Additional context:**
I'm trying to upload files using API. All it's done. But using web browser I have the problem.

**Server Logs:**

```
сен 11 17:45:03 cmnp-app-1 rocketchat[1098]: === UnHandledPromiseRejection ===
сен 11 17:45:03 cmnp-app-1 rocketchat[1098]: { Error: Match error: Expected string, got undefined
сен 11 17:45:03 cmnp-app-1 rocketchat[1098]: at check (packages/check/match.js:36:17)
сен 11 17:45:03 cmnp-app-1 rocketchat[1098]: at GridFSStore.Store.self.checkToken (packages/jalik:ufs/ufs-store.js:139:17)
сен 11 17:45:03 cmnp-app-1 rocketchat[1098]: at WebApp.connectHandlers.use (packages/jalik:ufs/ufs-server.js:149:24)
сен 11 17:45:03 cmnp-app-1 rocketchat[1098]: at /opt/Rocket.Chat/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/promise/node_modules/meteor-promise/fiber_pool.js:43:40
сен 11 17:45:03 cmnp-app-1 rocketchat[1098]: message: 'Match error: Expected string, got undefined',
сен 11 17:45:03 cmnp-app-1 rocketchat[1098]: path: '',
сен 11 17:45:03 cmnp-app-1 rocketchat[1098]: sanitizedError:
сен 11 17:45:03 cmnp-app-1 rocketchat[1098]: { Error: Match failed [400]
сен 11 17:45:03 cmnp-app-1 rocketchat[1098]: at errorClass. (packages/check/match.js:91:27)
сен 11 17:45:03 cmnp-app-1 rocketchat[1098]: at new errorClass (packages/meteor.js:725:17)
сен 11 17:45:03 cmnp-app-1 rocketchat[1098]: at check (packages/check/match.js:36:17)
сен 11 17:45:03 cmnp-app-1 rocketchat[1098]: at GridFSStore.Store.self.checkToken (packages/jalik:ufs/ufs-store.js:139:17)
сен 11 17:45:03 cmnp-app-1 rocketchat[1098]: at WebApp.connectHandlers.use (packages/jalik:ufs/ufs-server.js:149:24)
сен 11 17:45:03 cmnp-app-1 rocketchat[1098]: at /opt/Rocket.Chat/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/promise/node_modules/meteor-promise/fiber_pool.js:43:40
сен 11 17:45:03 cmnp-app-1 rocketchat[1098]: isClientSafe: true,
сен 11 17:45:03 cmnp-app-1 rocketchat[1098]: error: 400,
сен 11 17:45:03 cmnp-app-1 rocketchat[1098]: reason: 'Match failed',
сен 11 17:45:03 cmnp-app-1 rocketchat[1098]: details: undefined,
сен 11 17:45:03 cmnp-app-1 rocketchat[1098]: message: 'Match failed [400]',
сен 11 17:45:03 cmnp-app-1 rocketchat[1098]: errorType: 'Meteor.Error' },
сен 11 17:45:03 cmnp-app-1 rocketchat[1098]: errorType: 'Match.Error' }
сен 11 17:45:03 cmnp-app-1 rocketchat[1098]: ---------------------------------
сен 11 17:45:03 cmnp-app-1 rocketchat[1098]: Errors like this can cause oplog processing errors.
сен 11 17:45:03 cmnp-app-1 rocketchat[1098]: Setting EXIT_UNHANDLEDPROMISEREJECTION will cause the process to exit allowing your service to automatically restart the proce
сен 11 17:45:03 cmnp-app-1 rocketchat[1098]: Future node.js versions will automatically exit the process
сен 11 17:45:03 cmnp-app-1 rocketchat[1098]: =================================
```

Somebody knows whats wrong?

Thank You.

Comment: try using https instead of http it worked for me @dimson

Answer (score 3):

Please check if `Site URL` under general settings points to the public url of the application. I have seen instances where the upload is stuck when site url is incorrect

Comment: I have both the same, site url and the public url, and still upload stuck at 0%

Answer (score 2):

My roadtrip:

1. Change on File Upload the Storage File System
2. Set /tmp/ufs folder
3. chmod 777 on folder /tmp/ufs
4. Disable Protect sent files
5. Change Site URL to the same that you access.

Works perfect for me.

Comment: 4. Disable protect sent files
That's what fixed it for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure that `Site URL` matches the public URL. If you don't want to do this manually every time, make sure you set `ROOT_URL` upon deployment.

Answer (score 0):

Check that your "site url" setting is http**S** if your site is.

In my case (docker version) I could use rocket-chat messages 
with a non ssl "site url"

> http://example.com/chat

changing it to https allowed file upload

> https://example.com/chat

The setting is under

> Administration/Settings/General/"Site URL"